# UIAlertController Showing With Delay

Tags: swift, uikit, scenekit, uialertcontroller, xcode-instruments

I am having a lot of delay with my UIAlert, whenever it loads I have to wait before I can click and then again for it to fully disappear. I have looked at other answers that recommended using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {})`. I have tried using this but to no avail. The alert pops up during the render loop for a scene kit game I am making (the scene is just a cube and when I pause the scene it is still delayed). Shouldn't rendering be done in the render thread anyway. I looked the through the time profile log to see if something was blocking the Main Thread but I did not see anything that caught my attention (I fairly new to the instruments).[image: picture of call tree]

Here is my code where I am creating the alert:

```
func share(){
    print("share funciton")
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Share", message: "Where do you want to share?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Twitter", style: .Default, handler: {(alert: UIAlertAction!) in
        print("twitter")
        
        self.showTwitter()
    }))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
}

private func showTwitter() {
    if SLComposeViewController.isAvailableForServiceType(SLServiceTypeTwitter) {
        
        let tweetShare:SLComposeViewController = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
        
        self.presentViewController(tweetShare, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    } else {
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Accounts", message: "Please login to a Twitter account to tweet.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then I call share() when in the render loop with a dispatch_asych. I've been working at this bug for three days but have no idea what's causing the delay.

Comment: Simulator or device?

Comment: Do you accidentally have slow animations turned on?

Comment: @Wain just ran it. It works better (a few secs instead of 30)

Comment: Is animated the slow animations, I cant imagine it would be that slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try turning slow animations off. Open simulator -> debug -> slow animations

Comment: No worries this setting has been the source of a great deal of frustration for me in the past :)